# How to "sort and modify" a list?

Tags: arrays, c, list, sorting

I am not sure if this subject was already treated but if it's the case I did not have the right keyword to find it.
In my code I extract a mapping so let's say: `{5,0,23,2,2,0}`. As you can see the values are not contiguous. What I would like to do is transform this mapping so that the returned list is `{3,0,4,1,2,0}`. Here `0` means that the element should be ignored. So basically what I want to do is renumber the elements based on their order without moving them in the list.

I did that by first creating a copy of my initial array and then sorting this copy using `qsort` from the **stdlib** C library. I also created a `return_list` in which my final mapping will be stored.

(the initial array is `vec`)

```
    elt_count = 1;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (copy[i] != 0) {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (copy[i] == vec[j]) {
                    return_list[j] = elt_count;
                    vec[j] = 0;
                    elt_count++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here I use a counter to give the final mapping its values.

The problem is that this part of my method takes a lot of time and slows down my whole program while I was supposed to use the mapping to gain time.

I think I could store the position of each elements like this to try and improve the performances:

```
vec = (5,0,23,2,2,0)
5: (0)
23: (2)
2: (3,4)
```

However I am not sure how to implement this and then use it to gain performance.

Of course any other ideas to improve the performances are welcome !

Comment: So you want to replace each element by its position if the list was sorted and the 0s ignored ?

Comment: @Alex yes that's what I am trying to do. (it seems a lot simpler the way you said it, I may have over complicated it :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy approach is to make a copy of your array including the indexes of the values:

```
int a2[n][2];
int zeros = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    a2[i - zeros][0] = vec[i];
    a2[i - zeros][1] = i;
    zeros += (vec[i] == 0);
}
```

Now `a2` is an array of length `n-zeros`, and its entries are the non-zero elements of `vec` paired with their indexes.

Now sort `a2`:

```
qsort(a2, n - zeros, sizeof(a2[0]), cmp_a2);
```

Using this comparison function:

```
int cmp_a2(const void *v, const void*w) {
    const int *a = v;
    const int *b = w;
    if (a[0] < b[0]) return -1;
    if (a[0] > b[0]) return 1;
    if (a[1] < b[1]) return -1;
    if (a[1] > b[1]) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Now you can replace the original elements in the array, using the original indices stored in the sorted `a2`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n - zeros; i++) {
    vec[a2[i][1]] = i + 1;
}
```

Here's all the pieces together as complete working example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void print_array(int *a, size_t n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%s%d", i>0 ? ", " : "", a[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

int cmp_a2(const void *v, const void*w) {
    const int *a = v;
    const int *b = w;
    if (a[0] < b[0]) return -1;
    if (a[0] > b[0]) return 1;
    if (a[1] < b[1]) return -1;
    if (a[1] > b[1]) return 1;
    return 0;
}

void order_array(int *vec, size_t n) {
    int (*a2)[2] = malloc(n * 2 * sizeof(int));
    size_t zeros = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a2[i - zeros][0] = vec[i];
        a2[i - zeros][1] = i;
        zeros += (vec[i] == 0);
    }
    qsort(a2, n - zeros, sizeof(a2[0]), cmp_a2);

    for (int i = 0; i < n - zeros; i++) {
        vec[a2[i][1]] = i + 1;
    }
    free(a2);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int a[] = {5,0,23,2,2,0};
    size_t n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a);
    print_array(a, n);
    order_array(a, n);
    print_array(a, n);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response ! I have 3 compilation errors when compiling your code. One here: `const int *a = v;` and the line below and another one here: `int (*a2)[2] = malloc(n * 2 * sizeof(int));`. I corrected the first one like this: `const int* a = (int*)v;`. I don't even know if this won't break your code and for the second one i don't know how to correct it. Here is the error message: Conversion from 'void*' to pointer to non-'void' requires an explicit cast

Comment: Are you sure you are using a C compiler (and not a C++ compiler) to compile the code? The program compiles without warning using options `-ansi -pedantic -Wall -std=c99` under both clang and gcc.

Comment: Now that you said it I think I am working with a C++ compiler. The code I am working on is in C but the compiling tools used by my team are C++. I am going to try and find a way to make it work with this compiler. Anyway, it's clearer now that you gave me this method. Thank you for your response !

Comment: Note: `a2` is a pointer to array, which might make it difficult to find the correct casting syntax. You can use `static_cast<decltype(a2)>(malloc(...))` instead of `malloc(...)` to force the C++ compiler to accept this C syntax.

Comment: Thank you for this remark, I found a way to use C compiler so I don't have any trouble with that anymore. Your method is waaaaay faster than mine it's not even comparable !

Comment: I just need one clarification about your compare function. So if `a[0] < b[0]` it returns 1 and if its the opposite it returns -1. And the two lines under are made for the cases where `a[0] = b[0]` is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, for values that are the same (ie: `a[0] == b[0]`) it compares the original indexes so that duplicates in the original array get consecutive values with the left-most getting the lowest and the right-most the highest and so on.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the the standard library functions *qsort* and *bsearch* to solve the problem. Here is a start:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LEN(arr) (sizeof (arr) / sizeof (arr)[0])

int ElemDiff(const void *leftElemPtr, const void *rightElemPtr) {
    return *(int *) leftElemPtr - *(int *) rightElemPtr;
}

int main(void)
{
    int vec[] = {5, 0, 23, 2, 2, 0};
    int sortedVec[LEN(vec)];
    int i, *tail;

    memcpy(sortedVec, vec, sizeof (vec));
    qsort(sortedVec, LEN(sortedVec), sizeof sortedVec[0], ElemDiff);
    for (i = 0; i < LEN(vec); i++) {
        tail = bsearch(vec + i, sortedVec, LEN(sortedVec), sizeof sortedVec[0], ElemDiff);
        assert(tail != NULL);
        printf("%lld ", tail - sortedVec);
    }
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

This will print

```
4 0 5 2 2 0
```

Comment: The desired solution given in the question is `3, 0, 4, 1, 2, 0` not `4, 0, 5, 2, 2, 0`.

Comment: Yes, therefor I said "here is a start".